# create difference column of time series in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 2 columns, the date and the value for the date, e.g.

```
date         value
2015-09-01   15
2015-09-02   17
2015-09-03   21
```

and I want to create a column with the difference between the value and the value of the last day, like

```
date         difference
2015-09-01   NULL
2015-09-02   2
2015-09-03   4
```

Can this be done with MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## PROPOSED QUERY #1

```
SET @diff = NULL;
SET @prevval = -1;
SELECT date,
    (@diff:=IF(@prevval=-1,NULL,value - @prevval)) difference,
    (@prevval:=value) prevval
FROM mytable;
```

## SAMPLE DATA

```
mysql> DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS tover;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.03 sec)

mysql> CREATE DATABASE tover;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> USE tover
Database changed
mysql> CREATE TABLE mytable
    -> (
    -> id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    -> date date,
    -> value int,
    -> PRIMARY KEY (id)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.05 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO mytable (date,value) VALUES ('2015-09-01',15);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO mytable (date,value) VALUES ('2015-09-02',17);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO mytable (date,value) VALUES ('2015-09-03',21);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM mytable;
+----+------------+-------+
| id | date       | value |
+----+------------+-------+
|  1 | 2015-09-01 |    15 |
|  2 | 2015-09-02 |    17 |
|  3 | 2015-09-03 |    21 |
+----+------------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

## PROPOSED QUERY #1 EXECUTED

```
mysql> SET @diff = NULL;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET @prevval = -1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT date,
    ->     (@diff:=IF(@prevval=-1,NULL,value - @prevval)) difference,
    ->     (@prevval:=value) prevval
    -> FROM mytable;
+------------+------------+---------+
| date       | difference | prevval |
+------------+------------+---------+
| 2015-09-01 |       NULL |      15 |
| 2015-09-02 |          2 |      17 |
| 2015-09-03 |          4 |      21 |
+------------+------------+---------+
3 rows in set (0.02 sec)

mysql>
```

## PROPOSED QUERY #2

```
SET @diff = NULL;
SET @prevval = -1;
SELECT date,difference
FROM (SELECT date,
    (@diff:=IF(@prevval=-1,NULL,value - @prevval)) difference,
    (@prevval:=value) prevval
FROM mytable) A;
```

## PROPOSED QUERY #2

This will give you the exact output you display in the question

```
mysql> SET @diff = NULL;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET @prevval = -1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT date,difference
    -> FROM (SELECT date,
    ->     (@diff:=IF(@prevval=-1,NULL,value - @prevval)) difference,
    ->     (@prevval:=value) prevval
    -> FROM mytable) A;
+------------+------------+
| date       | difference |
+------------+------------+
| 2015-09-01 |       NULL |
| 2015-09-02 |          2 |
| 2015-09-03 |          4 |
+------------+------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It has been very helpful. I would like to add that the table has to be ordered for this to work.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It would need an `ORDER BY` and corresponding indexes.

Comment: Is there a way to extend this method to make sure that if a day is missing completely there will be no difference calculated?

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps. It's SQL Server code, but you should be able to perform the same join on your table with the `date_add` function.

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE ([Date] Datetime, [Value] int);

INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES ('2015-Sep-01',11);
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES ('2015-Sep-02',13);
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES ('2015-Sep-03',15);
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES ('2015-Sep-04',20);
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES ('2015-Sep-05',68);

SELECT 
    Main.Date, 
    Main.Value - Previous.Value as [Difference]  
FROM @TABLE Main
LEFT OUTER JOIN @TABLE Previous 
    ON Previous.[Date] = DATEADD(DAY,-1, Main.Date);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    v.*, 
    COALESCE(TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, date, 
    (
        CASE WHEN @pDate > date THEN @pDate END
    )), 0) AS difference, 
    @pDate := date
FROM 
(
    SELECT id, date 
    FROM table
    UNION ALL
    SELECT NULL AS id, CURDATE() AS date
) AS v
INNER JOIN (SELECT @pDate := NULL) t
ORDER BY date DESC
```

or

```
SELECT 
    v.*, 
    COALESCE(TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, 
    (
        CASE WHEN @pDate < date THEN @pDate END
    ), date), 0) AS numdays, 
    @pDate := date
FROM
(
    SELECT id, date 
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT 1 AS id, '2015-01-01' AS date 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT 2 AS id, '2015-01-10' AS date 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT 3 AS id, '2015-01-15' AS date
    ) t
    UNION ALL
    SELECT NULL AS id, CURDATE() AS date
) AS v
INNER JOIN (SELECT @pDate := NULL) t
WHERE id IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY date ASC
```

Comment: Generally, code-only answers are discouraged.  Please take the time to explain your answer in a way that allows viewers to understand why your answer works well.